# Is possible in JAXB to filter out child elements with value of elements?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, jaxb

How can I get to the elements that have the value of the element specified by me?
For example, i only need map position element where element id = 2. 
This is my xml structure:

```
<table>
   <position>
       <id>1</id>
   </position>

    <position>
       <id>2</id>
   </position>

    <position>
       <id>3</id>
   </position>
</table>
```

I know that I can map with JAXB the entire file into two classes in this way:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@XmlRootElement(name = "table")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Table {

    @XmlElement(name = "position")
    private List<TableElement> tableElementList = new ArrayList<>();
}


@Getter
@Setter
@XmlRootElement(name = "position")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class TableElement {

    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    private String code;
}
```

Here is the problem. I do not want to map the whole structure (my file can have up to 300 elements), but only elements that meet the condition (id = 2).

Answer (score 0):

If you only want a part then you could use a streaming parser like StAX: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/example.html#bnbgh

Also you should have a look at [In JAXB or Xstream is it possible to Filter out certain Child Elements on Type/value during unmarshall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21161881/in-jaxb-or-xstream-is-it-possible-to-filter-out-certain-child-elements-on-type-v) for it looks similar.

Comment: A DOM parser creates a complete DOM and you stated: `I do not want to map the whole structure`.